# Index of object in Array<Prototocol> in Swift

Tags: cocoa, swift

I want to get the index of my current theme.
My theme list is declared the following way

```
var themes:Array<ThemeProtocol> = []
```

I tried using 
`let currentIndex = find(self.themes, self.currentTheme)` but it doesn't work.
[image]

I also tried using

```
func currentThemeIndex()->Int? {
        let indecies = enumerate(self.themes)
        for (index, item) in indecies {
            if self.currentTheme == item {
                return index
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
```

[image]
Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`==` requires that there be an equivalence operator for the two objects (think `isEqual:` from Objective C)

`===` is the equivalent of the Objective-C operator `==`

To get object equivalence operations to work you need to define an equivalence operator:

```
@infix func == (left:Vector2D, right: Vector2D) -> Bool {
    return left.x == right.x && left.y == right.y
}

@infix func != (left:Vector2D, right:Vector2D) -> Bool {
    return !(left == right)
}
```

This is all straight out of the Apple reference guide available for free through the iTunes book store.

Note that these functions are defined with module scope (ie., outside any class and/or struct declarations)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `ThemeProtocol` conforms to the `Equatable` protocol. Or use `===` instead of `==` when comparing, if you are sure there are no distinct instances that are 'equal'.